# How can I cache a button click on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to save in local cache when a user clicks a certain button. Basically a message shows up and the user clicks a button to not show the message again. I was thinking that the best way to achieve this is by saving that the user clicked the button in the local cache. How would I go about doing this? If you have a better way to achieve this functionality please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about javascript, try localStorage

```js
if (localStorage.getItem('user_clicked') === null) {
  alert('message');
  localStorage.setItem('user_clicked', true);
}
```

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a rails way of achieving this, but this works for me. Thanks!